# Changing "each" to "map"?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, each

I would like to refactor the method `full_deck` in my Deck class. Instead of using nested `each` I would like to do it more elegantly. This method is returning an array with all cards in the deck:

```
 class Deck

      def initialize(variation)
        @variation = variation
        @cards = []
      end

      def full_deck
        Card::SUITS.each do |suit|
          Card::RANKS.each do |rank|
            @cards << Card.new(rank, suit)
          end
        end
        @cards
      end
end


class Card
  attr_reader :rank, :suit

  SUITS = [:hearts, :clubs, :spades, :diamonds]
  RANKS = [:"2",:"3",:"4",:"5",:"6",:"7",:"8",:"9",:"10", :J, :Q, :K, :A]
  ROYAL_RANKS = [:"10", :J, :Q, :K, :A]

  def initialize(rank, suit)
    @rank = rank
    @suit = suit
  end
end
```

Comment: This isn't really the place for refactoring. Maybe you should checkout http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code refactoring. It should be asked on [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  def full_deck
    Card::RANKS.product(Card::SUITS).map { |arr| Card.new(*arr)}
  end
```

Untested, but I think that should work.

Edit: tested, and works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this even nicer using product method. 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-product

```
def full_deck
  Card::RANKS.product(Card::SUITS).map { |card| Card.new(*card) }
end
```